# How to connect with BLE to an unknown custom UUID?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I'm wondering if it is possible to connect to a BLE device with an unknown custom UUID, and if so, how?
From my understanding, you can use the base UUID for predefined services and characteristics. But if a peripheral device advertises a custom UUID, which is not known, how do you connect to it?

A more concrete example and my actual use is a Heart Rate Monitor (HRM). If this HRM uses the Heart Rate service then you can 'find' it using the base UUID with the Heart Rate service UUID (0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB in this case). But if a HRM would use a random UUID to advertise the heart rate, how would you be able to read it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not need to know UUID to connect to BLE device. You simple connect to device then read its services, characteristics, etc. However if a device has custom service then you should know its "protocol". Or use sniffer to analize it.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for the comment. Will try it soon